# react how to integrate multiple types of search functionalities

Tags: reactjs

**Games.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import Game from './Game'
import {useEffect, useContext, useState} from 'react'

const Games= () => {
    
    const [search, setSearch] = useState({
        titleSearch: '',
        category: 'all',
        version: 'all'
    })

    const handleSearchbar = e => {
        setSearch({...search, titleSearch: e.target.value})
    }

    const handleSideCategorySearch = e => {
        setSearch({...search, category: e.target.id})
    }

    const handleVersionSearch = e => {
        setSearch({...search, version: e.target.value})
        console.log(search.version)
    }


    return (
    <div className="container">

                <ul> /* Category Search */
                    <li onClick={(e) => handleSideCategorySearch(e)} id='all'><a>All Mods</a></li>
                    <li onClick={(e) => handleSideCategorySearch(e)} id='action'><a>Tech</a></li>
                    <li onClick={(e) => handleSideCategorySearch(e)} id='adventure'><a>Magic</a></li>
                    <li onClick={(e) => handleSideCategorySearch(e)} id='survival'><a>Sci-fi</a></li>
                </ul>

                <ul>

                    <li>
                        <label>Versions</label> /* Version search, how to integrate this? */
                        <select name="version" onChange={(e) => handleVersionSearch(e)}>
                            <option>All Versions</option>
                            <option value='v1'>v1</option>
                            <option value='v2'>v2</option>
                            <option value='v4'>v4</option>
                            <option value='v2.1'>v2.1</option>
                        </select>
                    </li>

                    <li className='search'> /* Search */
                        <label>Search</label>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Search mod..." onChange={(e) => handleSearchbar(e)} />
                    </li>

                </ul>

                <div className="all-items">

                {
                    games.map(game=> mod.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(search.titleSearch.toLowerCase()) > -1 // Searchbar works
                        ?
                        search.category === 'all'
                        ?
                        <Game game={game} />
                        :
                        search.category === mod.category // Category search works
                        ?
                        <Game game={mod} />
                        :
                        null
                        :
                        null
                    )
                }

                </div>
            </div>
    )
}

export default Games
```

**Game.js**

```
import React from 'react'

const Mod = ({game}) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{game.title}</h1>
            <p>{game.version}</p>
            <p>{game.category}</p>    
        </div>
    )
}

export default Mod
```

**Sample data**

```
const mods = [
        {
            title: 'A action game v2',
            category: 'action',
            version: 'v2'
        },
        {
            title: 'A action game v1',
            category: 'action',
            version: 'v1'
        },
        {
            title: 'A survival game v4',
            category: 'survival',
            version: 'v4'
        },
        {
            title: 'A survival game v2.1',
            category: 'survival',
            version: 'v2.1'
        },
        {
            title: 'A adventure game v1',
            category: 'survival',
            version: 'v1'
        }
    ]
```

Basically, in games.js the user can search games with the searchbar and categories, but I want them to able select a version and only show games that have that version too (and of course the current category and whatever they are searching for), I dont think it will work the way I have implemented because I'm sure there is a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be mixing in filtering with the mapping. The `.map` should return a 1-1 length array of values for what it iterated over. The solution here is to first run the `games` data through a `.filter`. If you want all search filters to narrow further the results then you want to logical AND the filtering.

```
games.filter(game => {
  const { titleSearch, category, version } = search;

  if (titleSearch || category !== 'all' || version !== 'all') {
    if (titleSearch && (category !== 'all' || version !== 'all')) {

      // filter by title AND (category OR version)
      return game.title.toLowerCase().includes(titleSearch.toLowerCase())
        && (game.category === category || game.version === version);
    }

    // filter by title
    return game.title.toLowerCase().includes(titleSearch.toLowerCase());
  }

  // no filter to apply, return all elements
  return true;
}).map(game => ..... )
```

This could probably also be simplified a bit since all strings include the empty string (`""`).

```
games.filter(game => {
  const { titleSearch, category, version } = search;

  if (titleSearch && (category !== 'all' || version !== 'all')) {

    // filter by title AND (category OR version)
    return game.title.toLowerCase().includes(titleSearch.toLowerCase())
      && (game.category === category || game.version === version);
  }

  // filter by title, "" returns true
  return game.title.toLowerCase().includes(titleSearch.toLowerCase());
}).map(game => ..... )
```

```js
const games = [
  {
    title: "A action game v2",
    category: "action",
    version: "v2"
  },
  {
    title: "A action game v1",
    category: "action",
    version: "v1"
  },
  {
    title: "A survival game v4",
    category: "survival",
    version: "v4"
  },
  {
    title: "A survival game v2.1",
    category: "survival",
    version: "v2.1"
  },
  {
    title: "A adventure game v1",
    category: "survival",
    version: "v1"
  }
];

const search = {
  titleSearch: "game",
  category: "All",
  version: "v1"
};

const res = games.filter((game) => {
  const { titleSearch, category, version } = search;

  if (titleSearch && (category !== "all" || version !== "all")) {
    // filter by title AND (category OR version)
    return (
      game.title.toLowerCase().includes(titleSearch.toLowerCase()) &&
      (game.category === category || game.version === version)
    );
  }
  // filter by title, "" returns true
  return game.title.toLowerCase().includes(titleSearch.toLowerCase());
});

console.log(res);
```